# clips: avoiding connective constraints

Tags: clips

Let's suppose we have the following CLIPS template and rule:

```lisp
;; The queue sequence starts at 0.
;; -1 is a placeholder value to identify a newly inserted element.
;; The idea is to put a newly inserted element at the end of the queue.
(deftemplate queue-element
    (slot order (type INTEGER) (default -1))

(deftemplate put-at-the-end
    ?e1 <- (queue-element (order -1))
    ?e2 <- (queue-element (order ?o1))
    (not (queue-element (order ?o2&:(> ?o2 ?o1))))
  =>
    (modify ?e1 (order (+ ?o1 + 1))))
```

Is there a way to move the "connective constraint" `(> ?o2 ?o1)` out of the  pattern and move it to something similar to a `(test (> ?o2 ?o1))` construct instead?

The idea is to avoid these in-line conditions enterily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **and** conditional element to place several conditional elements within a **not** conditional element.

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate queue-element
    (slot order (type INTEGER) (default -1)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule put-at-the-end
    ?e1 <- (queue-element (order -1))
    ?e2 <- (queue-element (order ?o1))
    (not (and (queue-element (order ?o2))
              (test (> ?o2 ?o1))))
  =>
    (modify ?e1 (order (+ ?o1 1))))
CLIPS>
```

Comment: I didn't think about it. Thanks.